# How can I fill missing values over a particular group in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2020, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021],
                   'Cat1': ['level1', 'level1', 'level1', 'level1', 'level2', 'level2', 'level2', 'level2'],
                   'Cat2': ['sublevel1', 'sublevel1', 'sublevel1', 'sublevel1', 'sublevel2', 'sublevel2', 'sublevel2', 'sublevel2'],
                   'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})

   Year    Cat1       Cat2  value
0  2020  level1  sublevel1      1
1  2021  level1  sublevel1      2
2  2022  level1  sublevel1      3
3  2022  level1  sublevel1      4
4  2018  level2  sublevel2      5
5  2019  level2  sublevel2      6
6  2020  level2  sublevel2      7
7  2021  level2  sublevel2      8
```

I would like to take the unique values across the column 'Year' and duplicate the values of Cat1 and Cat2, filling the resulting value with 0, the result being:

```
    Year    Cat1       Cat2  value
0   2018  level1  sublevel1      0
1   2019  level1  sublevel1      0
2   2020  level1  sublevel1      1
3   2021  level1  sublevel1      2
4   2022  level1  sublevel1      3
5   2022  level1  sublevel1      4
6   2018  level2  sublevel2      5
7   2019  level2  sublevel2      6
8   2020  level2  sublevel2      7
9   2021  level2  sublevel2      8
10  2022  level2  sublevel2      0
```

I thought about using groupby() but I'm not sure it would work as I would like to preserve rows where there are duplicates across Year such as those on index 2 and 3. I also had a look at trying it with setting Year as the index and using set_index() with unique values of Year to pad it out but that doesn't seem to work on values where there are duplicates.

Other tries with groupby() led to values I did not want too e.g. returning rows with level1 and sublevel2 which I want to avoid.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Not a valid duplicate, classical methods to add missing values don't work if there are duplicated combinations (like here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `set` operation (and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)) to identify the missing years per group, then craft the missing rows and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them back to the original data:

```
# all existing years
# this could also be manually defined: years = set(range(2028, 2023))
years = set(df['Year'])

# identify missing years per group
# create new rows
missing = (df
   .groupby(['Cat1', 'Cat2'])['Year'].agg(set).rsub(years)
   .explode().reset_index(name='Year')
   .assign(value=0)
)

# concat to original
out = (pd.concat([df, missing])
         .sort_values(by=['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Year'], ignore_index=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
    Year    Cat1       Cat2  value
0   2018  level1  sublevel1      0
1   2019  level1  sublevel1      0
2   2020  level1  sublevel1      1
3   2021  level1  sublevel1      2
4   2022  level1  sublevel1      3
5   2022  level1  sublevel1      4
6   2018  level2  sublevel2      5
7   2019  level2  sublevel2      6
8   2020  level2  sublevel2      7
9   2021  level2  sublevel2      8
10  2022  level2  sublevel2      0
```

Comment: I was going to say congrats on 200k but then I looked more closely... :)

Comment: I guess I'll say it in the next day or so...

Answer (score 2):

One option is with [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor 
(df
# you can skip sort if you are not fuzzy about order
.complete('Year', ('Cat1','Cat2'),sort=True) 
.fillna({'value':0})
.astype({'value':int})
)   
    Year    Cat1       Cat2  value
0   2018  level1  sublevel1      0
1   2018  level2  sublevel2      5
2   2019  level1  sublevel1      0
3   2019  level2  sublevel2      6
4   2020  level1  sublevel1      1
5   2020  level2  sublevel2      7
6   2021  level1  sublevel1      2
7   2021  level2  sublevel2      8
8   2022  level1  sublevel1      3
9   2022  level1  sublevel1      4
10  2022  level2  sublevel2      0
```

Note how the `Cat` columns are wrapped in a tuple - the function treats them together; you'd get a different output if it was like this -> `'Year', 'Cat1','Cat2'`.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the desired result by creating a new DataFrame that contains the unique values of the 'Year' column and then merging it with the original DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2020, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021],
                   'Cat1': ['level1', 'level1', 'level1', 'level1', 'level2', 'level2', 'level2', 'level2'],
                   'Cat2': ['sublevel1', 'sublevel1', 'sublevel1', 'sublevel1', 'sublevel2', 'sublevel2', 'sublevel2', 'sublevel2'],
                   'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})

# Create a DataFrame with unique 'Year' values
unique_years = pd.DataFrame({'Year': df['Year'].unique()})

# Merge the unique_years DataFrame with the original DataFrame using a left join
result = unique_years.merge(df, on=['Year', 'Cat1', 'Cat2'], how='left').fillna({'value': 0})

print(result)
```

This code will give you the desired output:

```
    Year    Cat1       Cat2  value
0   2020  level1  sublevel1      1.0
1   2021  level1  sublevel1      2.0
2   2022  level1  sublevel1      3.0
3   2018  level1  sublevel1      0.0
4   2019  level1  sublevel1      0.0
5   2018  level2  sublevel2      5.0
6   2019  level2  sublevel2      6.0
7   2020  level2  sublevel2      7.0
8   2021  level2  sublevel2      8.0
```

Comment: This answer is not correct, it is missing `5   2022  level1  sublevel1      4`

Comment: @Nick OK, then it's what I thought, someone keeps upvoting other answers whenever I answer regardless of their validity, just to hold a grudge against me I guess. Very stupid… :)